# MySQL damaged, unable to login to connect and root password is no longer working

Tags: mysql

I have a VPS with MySQL. My MySQL seems to be damaged as when I do `service mysql restart`, it show:

> “Checking for tables which need an upgrade, are corrupt or were not closed cleanly.”

I can't use `myisamchk`, it says that my `root` password is wrong. But it is correct. I also tried to reset with [this tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/).

I think it is a problem with the mysql database, but I can't figure how to repair it.

Comment: Does it report anything for that check?

Comment: With myisamchk, it ask for the MySQL root password. And when I put the password, it says that the password is wrong.

Comment: If there are errors I'd expect it to tell you after running that check. Not being able to login could just as well be a wrong password. Did you get any errors while following that tutorial to reset the root password?

Comment: No errors with MySQL password reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround: I exported all databases with MySQL safe mode (described in the password reset tutorial) as safe mode don't ask for password.

Then, I reinstalled entirely MySQL.